# Why additional #import in bridging header failed in swift?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, bridging-header, xcode6-beta7

Before I added a new dependency to my test project via CocoaPods, I have already added a C header file ('wahoo.h') and exposed it to the swift code via a bridging header file "wahoo-Bridging-Header.h". The test app could be compiled and run without any problem.

Then I added a new dependency 'STHTTPRequest' to my project. You can see the list of file here:

[image]

If I added this line:

`#include <STHTTPRequest/STHTTPRequest.h>`

It will fail to compile with this error message:

[image]

I have tried a few alternatives but they all failed:

`#include "STHTTPRequest.h"`

`#import "STHTTPRequest.h"`

Apparently I cannot have more than one bridging header file in a project. How can I fix this import problem?

**EDIT** I can get around the problem if I copy the header file from `Pods` into `SO1` and add `#include "SO1/STHTTPRequest.h"` to the bridging header. It is not an ideal solution.

How can I automate the copying of header files? Or alternatively how can make header files in `Pods` accessible to `SO1`?

Comment: Does it work if you `#include "STHTTPRequest/STHTTPRequest.h"`?

Comment: The STHTTPRequest.h is in another project in the same workspace, have you tried the path where the file is in the project navigator? `<Pods/Pods/STHTTPRequest/STHTTPRequest.h>`

Comment: @Antonio That would not work, since file paths are in `<>`

Comment: @ViktorLexington: well that's what I see in my swift project - I am using several pods - but it looks like they are interchangeable, because I've just tried replacing `""` with `<>` and it compiles in both cases

Comment: @ViktorLexington Sorry it did not work

Comment: @AnthonyKong What's the relative path (from the directory containing your project)  of your bridging header in finder ? And what did you set in the build settings at Objective-C Bridging Header ?

Comment: Have the exact same issue, did you resolve it by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
#include <STHTTPRequest.h>
```

Comment: Add ${PODS_ROOT} as recursive and then it will start working

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell Xcode where to look for the header files you’re listing in the bridging header. Find the **Search Paths section**, and change the project-level setting for **Header Search Paths**, adding a **recursive** entry for the `Pods` directory. It should be **`Pods/**`** now.

In the Bridging Header include with:

```
#include <STHTTPRequest/STHTTPRequest.h>
```

or because of recursive search path:

```
#include <STHTTPRequest.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add the following header search path:
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/STHTTPRequest"

Answer (score 2):

I added "Pods/Headers/Public" as a recursive entry in the build settings for my project under "Search Paths/User Header Search Paths".

I then can use is standard import format: - #import "AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h"

Answer (score 0):

If your pod library in Objective c in that case you need to import class like this -

@import STHTTPRequest;